# How do I zoom web pages?

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, zooming

I'm using Android 4.2.2 on my Q.mobile. I am trying to zoom a (or any)  web page on Chrome by double tapping or by swiping two fingers but nothing happened. I also tried the same thing using the built-in browser but also in vain. How do I zoom web pages?

Comment: This is a sample site that prevent zoom-in on mobile: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/mobile-viewport.php (disclaimer: not affiliated with the blog and its creator, just want to give a sample site for easy test)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, some web pages do not let you zoom in. However, this can be overridden in *Chrome*.

[image: settings > accessibility]

Go to *Settings* -> *Accessibility* and tick mark *Force enable zoom*.

This overrides a web page's request to prevent zooming in. So then you can zoom into pages without trouble.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Take your index finger and thumb, spread them apart to zoom in. Conversely take your index finger and thumb, pinch them together to zoom out.

Make sure you have selected desktop view, mobile view won't zoom by default.

## Edit:

Double tapping does work in many browsers as well.

Comment: Or double tap will work in many browsers!

Comment: Thanks, I tried but nothing happened. Any other suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the website (or its mode) if zoom is supported.

Usually, you can't zoom if the site is on mobile mode. For Facebook, the URL would be https://m.facebook.com. However, some browsers like Dolphin or Boat have a setting to configure the default zoom, but sometimes they don't work. (e.g. Dolphin's setting doesn't work if Dolphin Jetpack is also installed)

On desktop mode, a site can be zoomable. For Facebook, the URL would be https://facebook.com.

Answer (score 0):

You may try by swipping two fingers or by double tapping on your display. Sometimes,some webpages don't support zooming, make sure that you have enabled desktop view because mobile view won't support zooming by default.